# Select list of dates in oracle

Tags: oracle

How to select the list of dates between two dates using oracle query?
For example, to select between 10-jul-2010 and 13-jul-2010, I want the query that returns:

```
10-jul-2010    
11-jul-2010
12-jul-2010
13-jul-2010
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select to_date(:start_date,'dd-mon-yyyy') + rownum -1
    from all_objects
  where rownum <= 
to_date(:end_date,'dd-mon-yyyy')-to_date(:start_date,'dd-mon-yyyy')+1
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution, you can add a where condition as well

```
select trunc(SYSDATE+level)
 from dual 
 connect by level <=365
```